# How to Use Blender API Documentation

Tags: blender

How does one use the existing Python API documentation for Blender (2.62) to locate the method that returns a material given its name, ie: "Material.001", etc.?

Normally, I'd use the console to see what Python calls are being generated as I do manual operations involving materials, but for some reason the most it will show is:

"bpy.ops.material.new()"

Note:  This is not so much a request for the name of the method as a request for meta-information -- information on how to obtain that information.  I have, of course, tried all the obvious routes:  blender site API searches, google searches, stackoverflow searches w/tags, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen Witold Jaworski tutorials: http://airplanes3d.net/pydev-000_e.xml

Answer (score 1):

As you already know right-clicking on every component of blender interface to go to the source code linked to that component is a very good way to learn Blender python API! I consider it the best.

Besides that, if I can't find an answer directly in the source code I use the search bar in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/). Please pay attention that Google often link you to an older version of the API documentation. Always look at the top bar or the URL to make sure you're in the right place.

Generally speaking, Blender API is just a collection of nested objects, mostly dictionaries of objects. So you could use a numerical index of key index to access them and eventually call their methods.

I find that the first 6 pages in [this](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/#blender-python-documentation) section of the Blender documentation pretty much cover all the *philosophy* of the API. If you haven't read them yet I suggest you to do it.